# How to add a subtitle file while playing a video using Quick Time Player?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, quicktime, subtitle

I have some questions regarding Quick Time Player in macOS.

1. Which type of subtitle files are supported by Quick Time Player ?
2. How to set a downloaded subtitle for a particular video via Quick Time Player ?
3. In VLC, there is a **VLSub** plugin to download subtitles automatically from Internet using VLC.
   Is there any plugin or option to do the same in Quick Time Player ?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1562590/which-type-of-subtitle-files-can-be-added-while-playing-a-video-using-quick-time

Comment: Whoever can answer it will answer it. I don't ever use QT for videos, I use VLC, which can do this automatically, so long as both files have the same name before the extension  [myMovie.mkv & myMovie.srt for example] & are in the same folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**QT Player 7+** on Mac still supports **.QT.TXT** and **.QT.SMIL** caption files,

For more info, visit [CaptionSync](https://support.automaticsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/202356865-Captioning-for-the-QuickTime-Player-overview#:%7E:text=NOTE%20FOR%20MAC%20USERS%3A,TXT%20and%20.).

There is no straight forward way to add, but you can use third party apps like **[Subler](https://subler.org/)** which helps you to attach it directly to the file and it's very fast.

Just download the zip, extract it and launch it.

After launching the app, then follow these steps :

- Open the app.
- Go to **File** menu.
- Select movie file of your choice.
- Click on **Open** Button.
- Drag your **.srt** file.
- Click on **Save**.

**Note:** I did it for mp4 file.

I haven't seen any plugin so far for QT Player similar to VLSub.

Comment: I found **Subler** tool very useful and it is supporting approximately all the file format, i.e, **.mkv**, **.mp4** and so on that I needed the most. Nice answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -i in.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 out.mov
```